# Data Load Issue

Tags: ssis

I started a load that ended up failing because of an SSIS error SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED This is just loading data from one table to another.  Wondering if I can start where it failed. So if 1000 rows were loaded Start a load from 1001.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, just change your source query to only include rows where the id is 1001 or greater.

If that doesn't answer your question, then you need to edit your question to make it more clear.   This does answer the question:

> Wondering if I can start where it failed. So if 1000 rows were loaded
>   Start a load from 1001